# What is the keyboard shortcut for Code Rush three periods?

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress, coderush, coderush-xpress

I know with ReSharper you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the "quick tasks" or whatever it's called.  Is there a similar keyboard shortcut for Code Rush?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially the answer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (Ctrl and back tick)

However in some scenarios this can set itself up as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> (Ctrl and single quote)

Note: I believe the reason for this comes down to codepages\keyboard layouts and other things I don't fully understand :)

Answer (score 4):

The common [shortcut](http://www.skorkin.com/2010/07/ide-tools-the-refactor-key-shortcut/) to invoke code refactorings and fixes in CodeRush is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) key combination. This shortcut invokes the popup menu which lists all operations available for the current context.

Answer (score 3):

It's configurable. [Mark Miller recommends setting it to NumPad 0](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2008/04/25/tips-for-getting-up-to-speed-amp-exploiting-the-power-of-coderush-and-refactor-pro.aspx) so your pinky can hit it as needed - careful though - you'll get addicted!